# X-Sendfile error, file not found

Tags: php, x-sendfile

I'm using apache2 webserver and I have installed mod_xsendfile
I have something like:

```
                header('Content-type: application/zip');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
                //header("X-Accel-Redirect: /file/protected/file.zip"); //for nginx server
                header('X-Sendfile: /protected/file.zip');
                exit();
```

I enabled in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
XSendFile on
```

When I click on Download button in /file/index.php it gives me error, index.php that is located in /file/ Not Found

I tried moving `header('X-Sendfile: /file/protected/file.zip');` at the first place but it's the same..

When I use `header("X-Accel-Redirect: /file/protected/file.zip");` It works but gives me empty .zip file, anyway its for not apache2 server..

File has only few KB

Anyone know how to fix it ?

**EDIT:**
It says in error.log: The given path was above the root path: xsendfile: unable to find file: /protected/file.zip

I set XSendFilePath /protected and the erro now is:
`(2)No such a file or directory: xsendfile cannot open file: /protected/file.zip,referer: http://domain.com/file/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the mod xsendfile documentation.  You have to set the directories that its allowed to serve files from.  If you've done that, then I would suspect some other issue, such as symlinks not being served, etc....

Comment: Do I have to set those directories in .htaccess file inside /file/ folder, in apache2.conf or in /sites-available/domain.com?

Comment: According to the docs (https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) the directive 
    XSendFilePath /abs/path

should work at either the apache2.conf level or in a .htaccess file (assuming allow overrides is set).